# Unity How to check if an operation is done?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So as you can see from title i need to check if my Vector3.Slerp function is done because i dont the code progress without Vector3.Slerp is finished. (Sorry for bad english)

Edit: just to clarify the question: im using a coroutine doing some Vector3.Slerp and i dont want all of them work at once i want one to be finished and other to start working.

```
IEnumerator func()
{
    Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos1, Time.deltaTime * 8f);

    //Check if Vector3.Slerp is done

    Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos2, Time.deltaTime * 8f);

    //Check if Vector3.Slerp is done

    Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos3, Time.deltaTime * 8f);

    //Check if Vector3.Slerp is done

    Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos4, Time.deltaTime * 8f);

    //Check if Vector3.Slerp is done

    Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos5, Time.deltaTime * 8f);
}
```

Comment: How can we help if you didn't include the code in your question?

Comment: _Sorry for bad english_ Your english is not the problem, but your question  is unclear

Comment: Ok im using a coroutine doing some Vector3.Slerp and i dont want all of them work at once i want one to be finished and other to start working

Comment: Use tasks, this question is very unclear, what have you tried so far?

Comment: A `Slerp` (or `Lerp`) with a third parameter of any value less than 1 will never complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to understand your question...sorry if I didn't understand.
Try something like this:

```
bool active = false;

void Update(){    
    if(!active){
       startCoroutine(coroutine());
    }
}


IEnumerator coroutine()
 {
    active = true;
    //your code
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    active  = false;
 }
```

**EDIT:**

```
IEnumerator func()
{
distance = 1;
while(distance > 0.1f){
    transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos1, Time.deltaTime * 8f);
    distance = transform.position - targetPos1;
    if(distance<0){
        distance *=-1;
    }
}

distance = 1;
while(distance > 0.1f){
    transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos2, Time.deltaTime * 8f);
    distance = transform.position - targetPos2;
    if(distance<0){
        distance *=-1;
    }
}
```

I didn't try this code...it's just to let you understand the idea. I've no time now but that's not a great code...You can do a lot better

Comment: Ok i edited my post to put my code i think now you can understand what im trying to do

Comment: Ok, I think you need to understand the slerp method: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html

I think that you need to cycle every slerp with a while until the transform.position isn't equal to the target position. The problem is that it will never be equal to the target, every cycle will be a bit closer. So you can check the distance between the 2 positions (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html). When the distance will be very little you can end the while.

Comment: Unfortunately you are both down the wrong track - No coroutines are in use here. 

Vector3.Slerp returns a Vector3, but nowhere in the test code is the return value being assigned.

Start with `Vector3 x = Vector3.Slerp(from,to,time);`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right but he could need coroutine for something else. As I said above I couldn't test the code, sorry if I missed something, it was just to explain the idea.

He just need to add "transform.position =  Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, targetPos2, Time.deltaTime * 8f);" 

Have I missed something else?

Comment: But you guys gave me ideas to make the system with another way so thank you all !